# sql query with a unique parameter in where statment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

so i have this query that works good and do some math

what i want to change is that only unique values of a third column

will Be taken into account

is this possible ?

thank u all!

```
SELECT t1.[customer_id] as customer_id,t2.total AS n_results ,                                                                                                                                               
         FORMAT((t2.total/t1.total)*100, 'N2')   AS fail_rate                                                                                                        
            FROM (SELECT [customer_id],                                                                                                                                      
                     1.0*COUNT( * ) AS Total                                                                                                                             
                FROM   [customer_transactions]                                                                                                               
              WHERE  [customer_id] != '' AND [customer_id] NOT LIKE 'D_%'                                                                        
              GROUP BY                                                                                                                                               
                       [customer_id]                                                                                                                                         
              ) t1 JOIN (                                                                                                                                            
              SELECT [customer_id],                                                                                                                                          
                     1*COUNT( * ) AS Total                                                                                                                           
                FROM [customer_transactions]  where  [result]='fail'             
               GROUP BY                                                                                                                                                  
                     [customer_id]                                                                                                                                       
              ) t2                                                                                                                                                   
                        ON t1.[customer_id]=t2.[customer_id] ORDER BY  fail_rate desc
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.  Please could you provide some example data along with the results you wish to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Query

```
Select Distinct fail_rate From
(
SELECT t1.[customer_id] as customer_id,t2.total AS n_results ,
         FORMAT((t2.total/t1.total)*100, 'N2')   AS fail_rate
            FROM (SELECT [customer_id],
                     1.0*COUNT( * ) AS Total
                FROM   [customer_transactions]
              WHERE  [customer_id] != '' AND [customer_id] NOT LIKE 'D_%'
              GROUP BY
                       [customer_id]
              ) t1 JOIN (
              SELECT [customer_id],
                     1*COUNT( * ) AS Total
                FROM [customer_transactions]  where  [result]='fail'
               GROUP BY
                     [customer_id]
              ) t2 
               ON t1.[customer_id]=t2.[customer_id] ORDER BY  fail_rate desc
)
```

Comment: for this iam getting 
Incorrect syntax near ')' -> for the last ')'

Comment: put any name after last bracket lets say ORDER BY  fail_rate desc ) as XYZ

Comment: SAME ERROR for

)ORDER BY  fail_rate desc

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct fail_rate From
(
SELECT t1.[customer_id] as customer_id,t2.total AS n_results ,
         FORMAT((t2.total/t1.total)*100, 'N2')   AS fail_rate
            FROM (SELECT [customer_id],
                     1.0*COUNT( * ) AS Total
                FROM   [customer_transactions]
              WHERE  [customer_id] != '' AND [customer_id] NOT LIKE 'D_%'
              GROUP BY
                       [customer_id]
              ) t1 JOIN (
              SELECT [customer_id],
                     1*COUNT( * ) AS Total
                FROM [customer_transactions]  where  [result]='fail'
               GROUP BY
                     [customer_id]
              ) t2 
               ON t1.[customer_id]=t2.[customer_id] ORDER BY  fail_rate desc
)
AS test
```